# Print spaces in between two strings using fprintf

Tags: c++, printf

I would like to use `fprintf` to print out two strings on the same line with spaces in between them.  The line has to be a maximum of 80 characters so I want the number of spaces inbetween the two strings to be 80 minus the lengths of the two strings.  This is what I have so far:

```
fprintf(pFile, "%s Statistics%80s\n", name.project, currentDateTime());
```

And I get this for my output:

```
AnotherProject Statistics                                                             2014-03-13.11:50:10
```

which is too long.  `currentDateTime()`'s string length will always return 20.  Is it possible to use `fprintf` for this scenario?

Comment: You could generate the format string first with `sprintf()`, inserting a variable with depending on your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the required field width and then use `%*s`:

```
const int fw = 80 - strlen(name.project) - strlen(" Statistics") - strlen(currentDateTime());
fprintf(pFile, "%s Statistics%*s\n", name.project, fw, currentDateTime());
```